# How to identify button in calc using AutoIT

Tags: autoit

I've seen this sample code..

```
Run("Calc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Calculator")
WinActive("Calculator")
Sleeper()
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button5", "Left") ;Click the number 1
Sleeper()
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button11", "Left") ;Click the number 2
Sleeper()
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button23", "Left") ;Click the + button
Sleeper()
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button16", "Left") ;Click the number 3
Sleeper()
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button28", "Left") ;Click the Equal button
Func Sleeper()
   Sleep(1000)
EndFunc
```

First few lines ok. but other lines Button 5, Button 11, etc if we count from Left side it is getting correct..

Instead, Is there any command Send(25), Send(+), Send(20) Send ("=")...

Comment: Run("Calc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Calculator")
WinActive("Calculator")
Sleeper()
Send("29")
Sleeper()
Send("{+}")
Sleeper()
Send("4")
Sleeper()
Send("=")
Sleeper()
Func Sleeper()
   Sleep(2000)
EndFunc

this is working fine.. Any other way???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Run("Calc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Calculator")
;this way you dont have to write separate statements for each button
ControlSend("Calculator", "", "#327701", "12345678")
;but you will have to write the statement for selecting operator separately
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button23", "Left")
ControlSend("Calculator", "", "#327701", "356")
ControlClick("Calculator", "", "Button28", "Left")
```

Edit:
 #327701 is:

[image]

Comment: "#327701, what it refers?

Comment: Thats where the text is displayed after you type. See my answer.

Comment: Oh! great. How to identify this no? #327701?? from, where you are taking this?? through autoIt co ordinates??

Comment: Search for Au3Info and drag the white circle over your calculator. It will give you properties of the app.